# pass a value of a derived type as template NTTP parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Should it be possible to pass a value of a derived type as NTTP?

```
struct base { };
struct derived : base { };
template< base name > struct component { };
struct test1 : component< ( base() ) >  { }; // OK
struct test2 : component< ( derived() ) >  { }; // error
```

C++20 (GCC 10.2) complains

```
error: conversion from 'derived' to 'base' in a converted constant expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of "converted constant expression" (which NTTP arguments must be) [specifically excludes](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#10) the possibility of derived-to-base conversions in the set of allowed standard conversions. This appears to be an oversight, as there's a [defect report on it](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2459).

So the C++20 standard at present doesn't allow them, though the intent is to fix it to make it possible. In the meantime, if you need to do this, you need an explicit conversion.

Comment: This was an oversight that was (partially) recognized before C++20 was published, but couldn’t be rectified immediately because there are surprisingly subtle issues with `this` (see [CWG2459](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2459)).  The intent is to allow the conversion, albeit perhaps with an extra (compile-time) copy.